# closed form for: $\frac{Q(x_1)}{P^{'}(x_1)}+\frac{Q(x_2)}{P^{'}(x_2)}+\frac{Q(x_3)}{P^{'}(x_3)}$

Tags: polynomials

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree $3$ $$P(X)=X^3+aX^2+bX+c$$ with real coefficients.

Let $x_1,x_2$ and $x_3$ be the roots of the polynomial $P$.

Let $R$ be a polynomial of degree $1$.

Find a closed form for:

$$\frac{Q(x_1)}{P'(x_1)}+\frac{Q(x_2)}{P' (x_2)}+\frac{Q(x_3)}{P'(x_3)}$$

This suggests to me that I have to find the following sums:

$$\frac{x_1}{P^{'}(x_1)}+\frac{x_2}{P^{'}(x_2)}+\frac{x_3}{P^{'}(x_3)}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{P^{'}(x_1)}+\frac{1}{P^{'}(x_2)}+\frac{1}{P^{'}(x_3)}$$

I was thinking about using:

$$\frac{P^{'}(x)}{P(x)}=\frac{1}{x-x_1}+\frac{1}{x-x_2}+\frac{1}{x-x_3}$$

But I cannot put $x=x_1$ in the latter equation and now I am kinf of stuck in a rut. How should I proceed?

Also, I am interested to know if there is a formula for:

$$\frac{x_1}{P^{'}(x_1)}+\frac{x_2}{P^{'}(x_2)}+...+\frac{x_n}{P^{'}(x_n)}$$
and
$$\frac{1}{P^{'}(x_1)}+\frac{1}{P^{'}(x_2)}+...+\frac{1}{P^{'}(x_n)}$$

where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with the roots $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$

Comment: What are $R$ and $Q$?

Comment: Also, you do not need to put ' in the exponent like you did. You can simply write `P' ` for $P'$. I adjusted it in one spot so you can see the difference.

Comment: You will probably find $\gcd(P,P')$ in the denominator of the answer as roots with multiplicity $>1$ cause the sum to blow up.

Comment: Yes, it looks one of $\ Q\ $ or $\ R\ $ is simply a typo for the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We suppose that:  for $i\neq j$ , $x_i\neq x_j$.

We know that $$\dfrac{Q(x)}{P(x)} = \sum_{i=1}^3 \dfrac{\alpha_i }{x-x_i}  \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \  \text{ with } \ \ \ \alpha_i = \dfrac{ Q(x_i)}{P'(x_i)}  $$

Then
$$\sum_{i=1}^3 \dfrac{ Q(x_i)}{P'(x_i)} = \sum_{i=1}^3 \alpha_i = \lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \left(x \sum_{i=1}^3 \dfrac{\alpha_i}{x-x_i}\right) =\lim_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \dfrac{xQ(x)}{P(x)} = 0$$

It's the same idea if $P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ with the roots $x_1,\ldots , x_n$